# In Dolittle how do different species speak to each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-voyage-of-doctor-dolittle

In the 2020 movie *Dolittle* (a.k.a *The Voyage of Doctor Dolittle*) there are humans and animals.

Doctor Dolittle has learned different languages of the animals, so he can communicate with any animal (of course all the conversations between those who know how to communicate are done in English so that us the viewers know what they are saying).

His sidekick (Tommy) also knows how to communicate with animals, but he needed more practice.

But how did the animals know how to communicate with each other? For example, how did the polar bear know the language of the ostrich? Did Dolittle teach different animal languages to all the animals? This seems very unrealistic. Because it takes an entire life to teach all animal languages to all animal species (and also learning of them). The animals even knew the humans' language (for example, after King Rassouli quarreled with Dolittle and told him to continue, the goose quacked to him, which translated to "we don't have a ship" by Tommy). Of course, no humans other than the two can communicate with animals in the movie.

Comment: *"This seems very unrealistic"* - I think you have your answer!

Comment: @Paulie_D - That doesn't mean that the filmmakers didn't discuss it, or include something in the film (or supplemental materials) to explain it

Comment: Same as the books - 'they just do'.

Comment: @Paulie_D "*This seems very unrelaistic*" isn't an answer. It just eliminates a probability. Is that the only probability? Of course not.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are all animals able to talk to each other in the books or it's just Dolittle who can speak with all of them?

Comment: The animals can speak to each other, it's just humans who can't. Don't look for 'good science' in any of this; they're children's stories. There's a lot of hand waving goes on. Things just **are** that way. Don't even ask how he gets to the moon & back;)